# Laplace transforms to solve ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

i've been working on this question for a while and can't seem to find the solution

Use Laplace transforms to solve the ODE
$$y''(t) + 2y'(t) + 5y(t) = e^{-t}$$

the initial conditions are y(0) = 1 and y'(0) = 1.

so far this is how I have progressed:

so generally $$y''+ay'+by=\mu$$ gives

$$(S^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0))+a(SY-y(0))+bY=\mu$$

this equals

$$(s^2 + as + b)(Y(s))=(s+a)y(0) + y'(0) + \mu$$

so using my equation i plugged in my values getting

$$(s^2 + 2s + 5)(Y(s))=(s+2)(1)+ 1 + (1/(s+1))$$

now i understand that you need to bring thee quadratic over and simplify so that you can do partial fractions. however my quadratic doesn't factorise, so i don't understand how else i can continue.

any help would be veryu appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you please complete rewritting your question using $ sign for math expersions

Comment: The work done so far looks good.  As you see, sometimes there are cases when its impossible to do partial fractions, and no other obvious tricks apply (maybe other than completing the square and seeing where that takes you). When all else fails, here are one's options: 1) try to do the inverse Laplace transform by definition, hard (see Wikipedia for Laplace transforms); 2) Solve the ODE another way, then see if you can work backwards from the solution to the expression you have; 3) See if Wolfram can manipulate and simplify your expression into a form you can use. If (2) and (3) fail, try (1).

Comment: no, not in closed form. i didn't know how to?